# how do i merge 3 select statements from different tables into 1 specific query?

Tags: mysql

i can write the specific query for that table and its relation, but merging them into one is the difficulty i'm having with

```
select clients, count(*)
from clients
inner join themes
on clients.id = themes.client_id
group by clients

select themes.id
from themes
inner join videos
on videos.theme_id = themes.id


select distinct videos.user_id, 
from videos
inner join properties
on properties.user_id = videos.user_id
group by properties.user_id
```

basically, i want to count the amount of unique users for a client

the relationship is

a client has many themes

a theme has many videos

a video has one property

a user has many properties

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the amount of unique users for a client:

```
select clients, count(DISTINCT properties.user_id) as num_users
from clients
inner join themes on clients.id = themes.client_id
inner join videos on videos.theme_id = themes.id
inner join properties on properties.user_id = videos.user_id
group by clients.clients_id;
```

You also might be able to get away with a bit shorter query:
Users always have properties (that is the assumption), then users with a video will be present in the property table and that then does not have to be joined:

```
select clients, count(DISTINCT videos.user_id) as num_users
from clients
inner join themes on clients.id = themes.client_id
inner join videos on videos.theme_id = themes.id
group by clients.clients_id;
```

Comment: its saying user_id is ambiguous, i think its because its a foreign key?

Comment: No, it needs an alias: field user_id is in multiple table: See updated answer